# C - printf error

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

I'm trying to compile an example from Sam's Learn C in 24 Hours.

When I try compiling the following code I get an error:

```
/* 03L02.c: Calculate an addition and print out the result */
#include <stdio.h>
/* This function adds two integers and returns the result */
int integer_add( int x, int y )
{
    int result;
    result = x + y;
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    int sum;
    sum = integer_add(5, 12);
    printf(“The addition of 5 and 12 is %d.\n”, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the errors my compiler gives:

```
In function main
stray "\147\' in program
The undeclared identifier is declared only once
for each function it appears in
syntax error before addition
stray "\' in program
stray "\148' in program
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your "quote" character is not correct. You are using “ instead of the default "

Comment: and looks like you have copied code from somewhere..

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong kind of quotes for the string in your program. You have `“` while it should be `"`.

Answer (score 1):

You just mistaken the quote character, change it to this:

```
printf("The addition of 5 and 12 is %d.\n", sum);
```

I don't know what keyboard you use, but usually the " character is above the '2' character (I am using an italian keyboard so maybe that's different for your country).
Surely you'll find that character somewhere.
If I'm not mistaken it's 34 in ASCII table, so on windows you can get it by pressing alt+34.

Answer (score 0):

because of wrong double qoute

```
printf(“The addition of 5 and 12 is %d.\n”, sum);
```

to

```
printf("The addition of 5 and 12 is %d.\n”, sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "smart quotes" in code!!!!! For string delimiters use plain old quotes. Here ("""""""""""""") are a few (here single quotes: '''''''''''''') you can probably copy/paste :)

Answer (score 0):

I see your error **because same character**. See your code

```
printf(“The addition of 5 and 12 is %d.\n”, sum);
```

**try change to:**

```
printf("The addition of 5 and 12 is %d.\n", sum);
```

can you see the differences? **the Qoute “ it's must be "**